# not receiving any AccessibilityEvent on scrollview update

Tags: android, android-studio, accessibilityservice

i created a accessibility service that listen event  and perform some specific action like automation.

i have a search field user can search train station and based on the search result user need to select a station from the searches. before start searching the screen shows popular searches.

i changed the search text programmatically

```
  arguments.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE,"bbs")
  fromNode?.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments)
```

after changing the text search results are updated on the screen but i am not able to listen and update after changing the text in form field.

but i am able to listen those events when i type manually on search field

is there any way to listen these events or explicitly read screen contents. to get the lates t changes on the screen.

for debugging you can use makemytrip app book train option through bus/train booking.